# How do I change a gray backround to a white backround in python?

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm trying to use `pyterreract` ocr to recognize characters on a part of my screen. It says that it can not detect any characters even though it is scanning some. I think the problem is that it has a gray background and the text is black for what I am trying to scan/ capture. I think the gray background throws it off, so I would like to change that gray to white and hope the software works. Here is my code:

```
imghi = ImageGrab.grab(bbox = (x, y, x + offx, y + offy))                             
imgglo = np.array(imghi)                                                                  
gray = cv2.cvtColor(imgglo,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)                                            
gray2 = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, None, 9, 13)                                         
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray2, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)                         
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))                              
morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(threshed, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)                          
Image_Inversed = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)                                                            
thresh = 0                                                                             
maxValue = 255                                                                                     
cv2.threshold(Image_Inversed,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)                                       
img_final = np.array(Image_Inversed)                                                      
cv2.imshow('Mats Viewer', img_final)                                        
tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\tyler\AppData\Local\Tesseract-  
OCR\tesseract.exe' text = tess.image_to_string(img_final)
```

If you are having trouble understanding, please comment. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your code does already remove gray background - it's in the line `th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray2, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)`, it sets all pixels with color value below 240 to 0 (white), and those with higher value to 255 (black).

The problem is that in further processing you don't use the image you've processed (`threshed`), but stick with the `gray` image instead. The same applies to other transformations you do - they are performed, but you assign the results to new variables which you don't use later on. It is important to understand that many operations (I'd risk saying it's generally default for most python libraries and cases) don't change the input *in place* - instead, they return a *new* object with some changes applied.

So, in short - in each line you process the image in some way you should use the output of previous operation, not the initial variable.

Comment: Thank you, I am a beginner at python and therefore can't explain my problems very well.